# Textarea doesn't show newline in IE

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer, textarea

Looks like IE ignores \r\n in text when the text is placed into a textarea. Here's how it looks in FF/Chrome/Opera:

```
Paragraph1 sometext
Paragraph2 othertext
```

And in IE7/8:

```
Paragraph1 sometextParagraph2 othertext
```

I tried changing "new-line" css parameter with no luck. Any ideas what might be wrong?

I use asp.net as back end, where I assign that text to the textarea, but I doubt it's relevant.

UPDATE: Seems like it's asp.net that is rendering asp:TextArea differently for different browsers - for IE it seems to ignore newline characters. When I replace asp:TextBox with textarea, I get correct results. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Do you see the newline if you look at the page's source code? That will let you see if it's a back-end or a front-end problem.

Comment: Hm, When I look at the source, I see new lines in Chrome, but not in IE. Might it be IE not giving me the correct source code? I doubt asp.net renders text differently for different browsers.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code where you set the text to the textbox.

Comment: @Mystere Man: txtMemberObjectives.Text = "Paragraph1 sometext\r\nParagraph2 othertext";

Comment: Ok, so is txtMemberObjectives an html `<textarea>` with a runat="server"?  Or is it a multi-line `<asp:TextBox>`?

Comment: It's a multiline asp:TextBox. Actually, it seems like it's being rendered differently in IE than in FF/Chrome - when I replace asp:TextBox with server side textarea, it shows correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my problem has nothing to do with the textarea itself, but rather with the way I'm escaping the output and unescaping the input. I'll open another question for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

A newline is \r\n, not \n\r.  Yes, it makes a difference.

Comment: It's \r\n of course, I mistyped my question. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

textbox with "MultiLine" set to "TextMode" is the rendering to  so this is not the problem...

Comment: `<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"/>` is eq to `<textarea></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where if specifying the width for the TextBox that was marked as TextMode="MultiLine" was causing the above behavior. I solved it manually specifying Rows and Columns properties of the textbox.