# variables rendering in IE textarea takes out the formatting

Tags: php, javascript, variables, textarea

I have a textarea that receives a variable via php

```
  $boring = str_ireplace($boringa, "\r\n", $boring);
```

That variable is then chaged via js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.clickable").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("textarea#messageforfriends").val($(this).html());
    });  
});
```

So the textarea receives the new variable fine in everything but IE (of course) the br tags are being taken out?

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in the way IE handles linebreaks in textareas. Here are a couple of earlier posts you may find helpful.

- [jQuery textarea append newline behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159622/jquery-textarea-append-newline-behavior)
- [Textarea doesn't show newline in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690403/textarea-doesnt-show-newline-in-ie) (an ASP question but it contains some useful points)

Answer (score 0):

Usually IE ignores the type of (repeated)whitespaces and internally replaces them with a single space (%20). This happens in most of elements(because the whitespaces make no sense there for the rendering), except `<pre>` and `<textarea>` .

So if it is an option, use a `<pre/>`-element instead of an `<a/>`